# Using Binomial Theorem for proofs.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

I need to prove that:

$$0 = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(−1)^k$$

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Expand $(1+(-1))^n$ using the Binomial Theorem. Equivalently, expand $(1+x)^n$ and set $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

By [Binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem),
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k}.$$

Set $a=-1$ and $b=1$ to get the result.